# CommandButton action is not invoked

Tags: button, primefaces, action, jsf-2.2

Environment:

- Primefaces 6
- JSF 2.2

I'm trying to load a list before opening a dialog with the result but the button does not execute the action and not even open the dialog.
When I use onclick instead of oncomplete the dialog opens, but the action does not open either.

```
<p:commandButton id="btnSimulation"
                     type="button"
                     value="#{msgs.act_simulation}"
                     styleClass="Fright BlueButton"
                     actionListener="#{actuacioBean.simulacio()}"
                     oncomplete="PF('dlgSimulacio').show()"
                     update="frmActuacio:error_panel"/>
<p:dialog header="#{msgs.act_simulation}" widgetVar="dlgSimulacio" modal="true" minHeight="40">
    <p:dataTable var="reg" value="#{actuacioBean.simulacio}" 
                 emptyMessage="#{msgs.act_nonerecord}"
                 reflow="true">
        <p:column headerText="#"
                  style="text-align:left;">
            <p:outputLabel id="idRegistre" value="#{reg}">
                    <f:attribute name="pattern" value="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>
                    <f:converter converterId="localDateTimeConverter"/>
            </p:outputLabel>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:dialog>
```

**Method**

```
public void simulacio() {
        try {
            simulacio = actuacioSvc.simulacio(actuacio);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesUtils.addErrorMessage("No s'ha pogut fer la simulacio: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to the core problem, but you need to update the content of your dialog before opening it or else you will be presented with the old or empty data.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/880619

Comment: first of all separate them (the dialog and the commandbutton) second call the dialog from your managedBean it will be better